# Selection on XAMPP

Tags: sql, xampp

I'm a college student and now i'm learning about `xampp` and `SQL`
So i have a project

i want to use it in `SQL XAMPP` but that constraint is error
Can anyone help me to fix this?

```
Create table Customer(
CustomerID char(5) Primary Key,
Name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
Gender varchar(10) NOT NULL,
Address varchar(100) NOT NULL,
DOB date NOT NULL,
Email varchar(100) NOT NULL,
Phonenumber varchar(100) NOT NULL,
Password varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT CheckCustomerID CHECK(CustomerID LIKE 'C[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
)
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2tDp.png) <<< press to see the error

Comment: Hi, please can you [edit] your question to include the *exact error message* you're seeing. Are you getting the error when running this `CREATE TABLE` statement, or when trying to do something with the table? Remember we can see only what you show us, so try to include any details you think might be relevant.

Comment: is it done?sorry im new on here

Comment: It would be better if you pasted or typed in the error as text; that way, other people with the same error in future can find your question, and people trying to answer it can see it without clicking through to the image.